# Mudar ordenação da tabela ao clicar em imagens em JS

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde preciso mudar a ordenação da coluna da tabela para decrescente ou crescente clicando nas imagens. para cima e para baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<table border="1" width="140px" class="sortable">
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">ID <img src="img/icones/cima.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/><img src="img/icones/baixo.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/></td>
        <td width="60%">NOME <img src="img/icones/cima.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/><img src="img/icones/baixo.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td width="40%">4</td>
        <td width="60%">João</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">2</td>
        <td width="60%">Maria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">1</td>
        <td width="60%">Pedro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">3</td>
        <td width="60%">Antonia</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando o jQuery pode usar o plugin http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Baixe o jquery desejado e depois baixe o `jquery.tablesorter.min.js`:

- http://jquery.com/download/
- https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.min.js

Repositório: https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter

Recomendo que use `<th>` pro cabeçalho da tabela e use `<thead>` e `<tbody>` pra separar.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $(".sortable").tablesorter();
});
</script>

<table border="1" width="140px" class="sortable">
    <thead> 
    <tr>
        <th width="40%">ID <img src="img/icones/cima.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/><img src="img/icones/baixo.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/></th>
        <th width="60%">NOME <img src="img/icones/cima.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/><img src="img/icones/baixo.png" width="9" height="10"  alt=""/></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
 <tr>
        <td width="40%">4</td>
        <td width="60%">João</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">2</td>
        <td width="60%">Maria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">1</td>
        <td width="60%">Pedro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="40%">3</td>
        <td width="60%">Antonia</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: tem como ao clicar na imagem?

Comment: @gezer vou tentar algo e edito, só uma dica se colocar somente na imagem o clique alguns usuários com problema de visão ou idade mais avançada podem ter dificuldades

Comment: ficarei grato @Guilherme Nascimento ate o momento não encontrei nada.